# Working out which months are in the past based on the month in character format

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to work out if a month is in the past but when the month is in character format. They could be changed to numeric format to make it easier but I wanted to try first.

So here the month in question is August and as our current month is Septemper I want the following statement to be TRUE.

```
mymonth = 'Aug'
month.abb[month(Sys.Date())] > mymonth
```

On this occasion it does return TRUE but when I change my month to Oct it still returns TRUE which is incorrect. I'm pretty sure it's because R cant't actually recognize the different in a character string but let me know if theres any way this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the index of the current month and compare that with the index of the month you want to compare by using `match` to find its index of the `month.abb` vector like this:

```r
library(lubridate)
mymonth = c('Aug', "Oct")

month(Sys.Date()) > match(mymonth, month.abb)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `month.abb[month(Sys.Date())]`, it returns `"Sep"`, and using relational operators `>` on strings doesn't really make sense.

Therefore, you should first figure out the numeric index of `mymonth` in `month.abb`, and compare the numerical month returned by `month(Sys.Date())` with the numeric index.

```r
library(lubridate)

mymonth = 'Aug'

month(Sys.Date()) > which(month.abb == mymonth)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make an ordered factor for the months then your code should work -

```
order_month <- factor(month.abb, levels = month.abb, ordered = TRUE)

#[1] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < Jul < Aug < Sep < Oct < Nov < Dec

library(lubridate)
mymonth = 'Aug'
order_month[month(Sys.Date())] > mymonth
#[1] TRUE
```